# Undefined variable in GoogleMap JSX component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, undefined, serverside-javascript

In my application, i have the following code snippet from the beginning of my Google Map JSX component (which was written by someone else):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {GoogleMapLoader, GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow, DirectionsRenderer} from 'react-google-maps';
import {
  default as canUseDOM,
} from "can-use-dom";
const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
```

When i utilize client-side rendering and execute this code on the client, it runs without error with expected behaviour. However, when i switch to server-side rendering using ReactDOM.renderToString(), I encounter following error:

```
var DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                            ^
ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

Looking at the code in detail. The variable "google" is really not defined anywhere before in my code.

My questions are:

1. Where is the variable "google" defined?
2. Why the client side rendering performs OK, while server side throws error?

Thank you very much for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `google` comes from `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js` which is [loaded](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/5e672b92f3e47861126349a5691c33b9b1d1eb88/examples/gh-pages/src/pages/AsyncGettingStarted.js#L128) asynchronously on the client.

On the server, this script is not loaded and things break. It appears the [component you are using](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) is not fully isomorphic, so it will only work on the client side.

I've used [google-map-react](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react) in the past, highly recommended and fully isomorphic.